# how do I stop sbt from downloading so many jars?

Tags: scala, sbt

Every time I run sbt in a new folder, I have to wait for a couple minutes while it does downloads a bunch of jars (see log output below).  This is really annoying, and will be a problem when I work offline (which is often).  How can I stop this behavior and make sbt look in a local folder for its dependencies?

In case it's relevant, I installed sbt from a .deb file on Ubuntu

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.9  (this may take some time)...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/jars/sbt.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9!sbt.jar (2695ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.5/scala-library-2.10.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.5!scala-library.jar (738ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.9/jars/main.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.9!main.jar (2753ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.9/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.9!compiler-interface-bin.jar (2284ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.9/jars/compiler-interface-src.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.9!compiler-interface-src.jar (1665ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_8_2/0.13.9/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.9!compiler-interface-bin.jar (2323ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_2/0.13.9/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.9!compiler-interface-bin.jar (2207ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_3/0.13.9/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.9!compiler-interface-bin.jar (2221ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/actions/0.13.9/jars/actions.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.9!actions.jar (2190ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.9/jars/main-settings.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.9!main-settings.jar (1976ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/interface/0.13.9/jars/interface.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.9!interface.jar (1945ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.9/jars/io.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.9!io.jar (1842ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.9/jars/ivy.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.9!ivy.jar (1799ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/logging/0.13.9/jars/logging.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logging;0.13.9!logging.jar (2172ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/logic/0.13.9/jars/logic.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.9!logic.jar (2266ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/process/0.13.9/jars/process.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#process;0.13.9!process.jar (1855ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/run/0.13.9/jars/run.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.9!run.jar (1585ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/command/0.13.9/jars/command.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.9!command.jar (1693ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/classpath/0.13.9/jars/classpath.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.13.9!classpath.jar (1947ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/completion/0.13.9/jars/completion.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.9!completion.jar (2204ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/api/0.13.9/jars/api.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.9!api.jar (1901ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-integration/0.13.9/jars/compiler-integration.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.13.9!compiler-integration.jar (2196ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-ivy-integration/0.13.9/jars/compiler-ivy-integration.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.9!compiler-ivy-integration.jar (1305ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/relation/0.13.9/jars/relation.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#relation;0.13.9!relation.jar (1437ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/task-system/0.13.9/jars/task-system.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.9!task-system.jar (1553ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/tasks/0.13.9/jars/tasks.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.9!tasks.jar (1774ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/tracking/0.13.9/jars/tracking.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.9!tracking.jar (1683ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/testing/0.13.9/jars/testing.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.9!testing.jar (1425ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.5/scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.5!scala-compiler.jar (1555ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.5/scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5!scala-reflect.jar (305ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/control/0.13.9/jars/control.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.9!control.jar (1525ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/collections/0.13.9/jars/collections.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.9!collections.jar (2354ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.11/jline-2.11.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] jline#jline;2.11!jline.jar (45ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.9/jars/incremental-compiler.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.9!incremental-compiler.jar (2149ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.9/jars/compile.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.9!compile.jar (2200ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/persist/0.13.9/jars/persist.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#persist;0.13.9!persist.jar (1896ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/classfile/0.13.9/jars/classfile.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.13.9!classfile.jar (1704ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/cross/0.13.9/jars/cross.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cross;0.13.9!cross.jar (1682ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-c5d1b95fdcc1e1007740ffbecf4eb07abc51ec93/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-c5d1b95fdcc1e1007740ffbecf4eb07abc51ec93.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-c5d1b95fdcc1e1007740ffbecf4eb07abc51ec93!ivy.jar (215ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.46/jsch-0.1.46.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.46!jsch.jar (44ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/serialization_2.10/0.1.1/jars/serialization_2.10.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#serialization_2.10;0.1.1!serialization_2.10.jar (1912ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-pickling_2.10/0.10.0/scala-pickling_2.10-0.10.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang.modules#scala-pickling_2.10;0.10.0!scala-pickling_2.10.jar (97ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/cache/0.13.9/jars/cache.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.9!cache.jar (2559ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/test-agent/0.13.9/jars/test-agent.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.9!test-agent.jar (1619ms)
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/apply-macro/0.13.9/jars/apply-macro.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.9!apply-macro.jar (1581ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    52 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (17785kB/180ms)
Getting Scala 2.10.5 (for sbt)...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/jline/2.10.5/jline-2.10.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.5!jline.jar (51ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24493kB/92ms)
[info] Loading project definition from projects/project
[info] Updating {file: projects/project/}practiceassignment-build...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-c5d1b95fdcc1e1007740ffbecf4eb07[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/4.0.0/jars/sbteclipse-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0!sbteclipse-plugin.jar (2175ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalastyle/scalastyle_2.10/0.8.0/scalastyle_2.10-0.8.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalastyle#scalastyle_2.10;0.8.0!scalastyle_2.10.jar (142ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaj/scalaj-http_2.10/2.2.1/scalaj-http_2.10-2.2.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalaj#scalaj-http_2.10;2.2.1!scalaj-http_2.10.jar (33ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-codec#commons-codec;1.10!commons-codec.jar (91ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.4!commons-lang3.jar (121ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-core_2.10/7.1.0/scalaz-core_2.10-7.1.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.10;7.1.0!scalaz-core_2.10.jar(bundle) (986ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-effect_2.10/7.1.0/scalaz-effect_2.10-7.1.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.1.0!scalaz-effect_2.10.jar(bundle) (63ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalariform/scalariform_2.10/0.1.7/scalariform_2.10-0.1.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalariform#scalariform_2.10;0.1.7!scalariform_2.10.jar (188ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/config/1.2.0/config-1.2.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe#config;1.2.0!config.jar(bundle) (36ms)
[info] Done updating.
```

Comment: Additional information in the form of your `build.sbt`, `project/build.properties` and `project/plugins.sbt` would be useful. Normally, on a single PC `sbt` would only perform most of the operation above once per `sbt.version` in `project/build.properies` and corresponding Scala version, saving results in `%USERPROFILE%/.sbt/boot` (all paths given as on Windows, on other systems they should be similar). Parts of remaining operation performed once per version of plugin or dependency library and saved in `%USERPROFILE%/.ivy2/cache`, which also stores packages needed to `sbt` versions.